# Can't get output in select statement with unions. Oracle SQL r12

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, reportbuilder, oracle-apps

Under --Report Parameters, I have `V_ORG_NAME` displaying the organization name the report is being run under. I'm trying to get the output for the vendor name under `V_VENDOR_NAME`. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to add a second `IF` statement. I believe my problem falls under this section of my code, but I'm not sure how to edit: `IF '&1' IS NOT NULL` 
This is the error output in Oracle:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

I believe this part below isn't right but not sure how to edit or add to it.

```
 IF '&1' IS NOT NULL 
 THEN
  SELECT NAME
    INTO V_VENDOR_NAME
  FROM AP.AP_SUPPLIERS
  WHERE VENDOR_ID = '&1';
 END IF;

 :V_VENDOR_NAME := V_VENDOR_NAME;

 END;
 /

 COLUMN V_ORG_ID noprint new_value V_ORG_ID

COLUMN V_VENDOR_ID noprint new_value V_VENDOR_ID

COLUMN V_ORG_NAME noprint new_value V_ORG_NAME

COLUMN V_VENDOR_NAME noprint new_value V_VENDOR_NAME

SELECT :V_VENDOR_ID            V_VENDOR_ID , 
   :V_ORG_ID               V_ORG_ID    ,
   :V_ORG_NAME             V_ORG_NAME  ,
   :V_VENDOR_NAME          V_VENDOR_NAME
FROM SYS.DUAL;

SELECT DATA FROM (
-- Report Header
SELECT '1','INST Supplier Banking' DATA FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
-- Report Parameters
SELECT '2','Vendor: '||'&V_VENDOR_NAME'||' Org: '||'&V_ORG_NAME'
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
-- Column Headers
select '3','"Vendor Name"|"Supplier Number"|"Site Name"|"Bank Name"|"Bank Number"|"Branch Name"|"Branch Number"|"Account Name"|"Account Number"|"Description"|"Start Date"|"End Date"|"Creation Date"|"Created By"|"Last Update"|"Last Updated By"|"Address Line 1"|"Job Title"|"Email Address"'
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Is this in some tool or application that you are using? I don't know what `--Report parameters` are, and `flex-direction: column;` doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. You may have a look at [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question

Comment: --Report Parameters is text that's been commented out. Usually added to provide notes for other developers in the future.

Comment: Sample Data: 
INST Supplier Banking
Parameters: 89035 -> Instinet US (89035 is the Vendor ID that I'm trying to output as Vendor Name. The ID is of no use to an end user viewing this report)
"Vendor Name"|"Supplier Number"|"Site Name"|"Bank Name"|"Bank Number"|"Branch Name"|"Branch Number"|"Account Name"|"Account Number"|"Description"|"Start Date"|"End Date"|"Creation Date"|"Created By"|"Last Update"|"Last Updated By"|"Address Line 1"|"Job Title"|"Email Address"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're confusing Bind variables and Substitution variables.

A Bind variable is a PLSQL like variable that must be defined beforehand and will be "bound" into the SQL statement after parsing.
A Substitution variable is a string that will be "substituted" into the SQL statement before parsing. Take care to quote them, else they will be interpreted as column names.

Below you find an example  how to combine them:

```
VAR v_bind_name VARCHAR2(30)

BEGIN
    :v_bind_name  := 'Brad';
END;
/

SELECT :v_bind_name FROM sys.DUAL;

COLUMN SUBST_NAME NOPRINT NEW_VALUE v_subst_name

SELECT 'Pitt' AS subst_name FROM DUAL;

SELECT :v_bind_name AS first_name, '&V_SUBST_NAME' AS last_name FROM sys.DUAL;

SELECT *
  FROM ( -- Report Header
        SELECT '1', 'INST Supplier Banking' data FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        -- Report Parameters
        SELECT '2', 'Vendor: ' || :v_bind_name || ' Org: ' || '&V_SUBST_NAME' FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        -- Column Headers
        SELECT '3', '"Vendor Name"|"Supplier Number"|"Site Name"|"Bank Name"|"Bank Number"|"Branch Name"' FROM DUAL);
```